# what files from the JRE7 directory are actually needed to run Lucene?

Tags: java, php, lucene, jvm, elasticsearch

This is about running Lucene (actually Elasticsearch) in a website which is actually otherwise pure PHP... Clearly I need to have the "JVM" and a handful of Lucene jar files... But what does the "JVM" actually mean? Which of all these 125 MB of files under \jre7, if any, can just not be uploaded?

I presume I need "java.exe", but presumably not "javaw.exe", and "fontmanager.dll" doesn't seem that essential (for example).

I have tried googling about this but come up with nothing.

Supposing you wanted to install some Lucene-search-based app on your Android phone (which could be used offline to search through your stuff...)... how can you find what would actually be essential file-wise?

Comment: Why won't you just install the whole JRE? Trying to optimize some bytes?

Comment: well, 125 MB is quite a lot if you don't need all of it...  + I'm just interested... what is the minimal "JVM" you can get away with?

Comment: 125 MB of disk space costs about one cent, this is the same as spending 8 seconds of your time on minimum wage. Are you sure this is worth your time looking at?

Comment: Kayaman and Peter are right, *without any further information* we must discourage you to try this.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I concur... but for example in Android phones presumably they use a smaller set of files.  This is more about interest rather than saving disk space.

Comment: @mikerodent You wouldn't deploy you own modified JRE to an android phone. You would use the one already installed.  The problem is the effort and risk involved in modifying the JRE doesn't justify the notional gains.